# How to Set Automatic active = true in TextEditBox using brightscript?

Tags: focus, roku, brightscript

Is there any way to I add texteditbox and SetFocus(true) and his automatic set active = true in a bright script?

using SetFocus I set the focus on textbox Its display that's border and color. But SetFocus(true) not display a cursor. I set active = true its work but IS there any way to I SetFocus(true) only and the cursor is displayed in TextEditBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub init()
 m.TextEditBox = m.top.FindNode("myEditBox")
 m.TextEditBox.observeFieldScoped("focusedChild", "onBoxFocused")
end sub

sub onBoxFocused(msg as Object)
 box = msg.getROSGNode()
 box.active = box.hasFocus()
end sub
```

also, you can add there some other things, like background and etc, and it will be triggered by that event

Comment: I tried this code. In `onBoxFocused()` first line throw following error `--- Syntax Error. Builtin function call expected. (compile error &h9d)`.

Comment: I might have made a mistype.
It was just an example, though.
Check methods here: https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/events/rosgnodeevent.md